# (Python)Selecting most closest date to the end of month

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My goal is to choose the most closest date to end of month.
For instance, how to choose '2021-01-29', '2021-02-26' ?
(Some sort of masking method is available?)

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-01-28', '2021-01-29', '2021-02-25','2021-02-26']})

         date
0  2021-01-28
1  2021-01-29
2  2021-02-25
3  2021-02-26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grouping by month periods and get maximal value of datetimes:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('m')).max()
print (df)
              date
date              
2021-01 2021-01-29
2021-02 2021-02-26
```

Or use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices by maximal `date`, then select values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.loc[df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('m'))['date'].idxmax()]
print (df)
        date
1 2021-01-29
3 2021-02-26
```

Or first sorting and then get last duplicated row by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.sort_values('date')

df = df[~df['date'].dt.to_period('m').duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df)
        date
1 2021-01-29
3 2021-02-26
```